# android navigation drawer item click not working

Tags: android, navigation, navigation-drawer, onclicklistener

I'm using MaterialTabHost and NavigationView when i click on navigation drawer item but not working
NavigationView im using example code
Anyone help me fix
My code here

[enter image description here][1]

I think i wrong in function replace frament

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements MaterialTabListener {
    private String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    MaterialTabHost tabHost;
    ViewPager pager;

    ViewPagerAdapter adapter;
    private String[] tabs =  {"Home","Category","Favourite"};
    Toolbar toolbar;
    String strMessage;
    private AdView mAdView;
    private InterstitialAd mInterstitial;
    private String name, link;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;

    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private DrawerLayout drawer;
    private View navHeader;
    private ImageView imgNavHeaderBg, imgProfile;
    private TextView txtName, txtWebsite;
    private FloatingActionButton fab;



    // index to identify current nav menu item
    public static int navItemIndex = 0;

    // tags used to attach the fragments
    private static final String TAG_HOME = "home";
    public static String CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;

    // toolbar titles respected to selected nav menu item
    private String[] activityTitles;

    // flag to load home fragment when user presses back key
    private boolean shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress = true;
    private Handler mHandler;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            toolbar = (Toolbar) this.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
            toolbar.setTitle(getString(R.string.app_name));
            this.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

            tabHost = (MaterialTabHost) this.findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
            pager = (ViewPager) this.findViewById(R.id.pager );
            adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            pager.setAdapter(adapter);

            pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    // when user do a swipe the selected tab change
                    tabHost.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);

                }
            });

            for(String tab_name:tabs)
            {
                tabHost.addTab(
                        tabHost.newTab()
                                .setText(tab_name)
                                .setTabListener(MainActivity.this)
                );
            }
            //navigation

        mHandler = new Handler();

        drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);


        // Navigation view header
        navHeader = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);
        txtName = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.name);
        txtWebsite = (TextView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.website);
        imgNavHeaderBg = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_header_bg);
        imgProfile = (ImageView) navHeader.findViewById(R.id.img_profile);

        // load toolbar titles from string resources
        activityTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_item_activity_titles);



        // load nav menu header data
        loadNavHeader();

        // initializing navigation menu
        setUpNavigationView();

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
        }

            //end navigation



    }

//navigation

    private void loadNavHeader() {
        // name, website
        txtName.setText("Ravi Tamada");
        txtWebsite.setText("www.androidhive.info");

        // loading header background image
        Glide.with(this).load(urlNavHeaderBg)
                .crossFade()
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgNavHeaderBg);

        // Loading profile image
        Glide.with(this).load(urlProfileImg)
                .crossFade()
                .thumbnail(0.5f)
                .bitmapTransform(new CircleTransform(this))
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .into(imgProfile);

        // showing dot next to notifications label
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(3).setActionView(R.layout.menu_dot);
    }


    private void setUpNavigationView() {
        //Setting Navigation View Item Selected Listener to handle the item click of the navigation menu
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(new NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {

            // This method will trigger on item Click of navigation menu
            @Override
            public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem) {

                //Check to see which item was being clicked and perform appropriate action
                switch (menuItem.getItemId()) {
                    //Replacing the main content with ContentFragment Which is our Inbox View;
                    case R.id.home:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_photos:
                        navItemIndex = 1;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_PHOTOS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_movies:
                        navItemIndex = 2;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_MOVIES;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_notifications:
                        navItemIndex = 3;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_NOTIFICATIONS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_settings:
                        navItemIndex = 4;
                        CURRENT_TAG = TAG_SETTINGS;
                        break;
                    case R.id.nav_about_us:
                        // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeFragment.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    case R.id.nav_privacy_policy:
                        // launch new intent instead of loading fragment
                        startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeFragment.class));
                        drawer.closeDrawers();
                        return true;
                    default:
                        navItemIndex = 0;
                }

                //Checking if the item is in checked state or not, if not make it in checked state
                if (menuItem.isChecked()) {
                    menuItem.setChecked(false);
                } else {
                    menuItem.setChecked(true);
                }
                menuItem.setChecked(true);

                loadHomeFragment();

                return true;
            }
        });


        ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.openDrawer, R.string.closeDrawer) {

            @Override
            public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer closes as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            }

            @Override
            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                // Code here will be triggered once the drawer open as we dont want anything to happen so we leave this blank
                super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            }
        };

        //Setting the actionbarToggle to drawer layout
        drawer.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);

        //calling sync state is necessary or else your hamburger icon wont show up
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    private void selectNavMenu() {
        navigationView.getMenu().getItem(navItemIndex).setChecked(true);
    }
    private void loadHomeFragment() {
        // selecting appropriate nav menu item
        selectNavMenu();

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(CURRENT_TAG) != null) {
            drawer.closeDrawers();

            // show or hide the fab button

            return;
        }

        // Sometimes, when fragment has huge data, screen seems hanging
        // when switching between navigation menus
        // So using runnable, the fragment is loaded with cross fade effect
        // This effect can be seen in GMail app
        Runnable mPendingRunnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // update the main content by replacing fragments
                Fragment fragment = getHomeFragment();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(android.R.anim.fade_in,
                        android.R.anim.fade_out);
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.ad_linear, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);
                fragmentTransaction.commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }
        };

        // If mPendingRunnable is not null, then add to the message queue
        if (mPendingRunnable != null) {
            mHandler.post(mPendingRunnable);
        }

        // show or hide the fab button


        //Closing drawer on item click
        drawer.closeDrawers();

        // refresh toolbar menu
        invalidateOptionsMenu();
    }

    private Fragment getHomeFragment() {
        switch (navItemIndex) {
            case 0:
                // home
                HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                return homeFragment;
            case 1:
                // photos
                PhotosFragment photosFragment = new PhotosFragment();
                return photosFragment;
            case 2:
                // movies fragment
                CategoryFragment moviesFragment = new CategoryFragment();
                return moviesFragment;
            case 3:
                // notifications fragment
                CategoryFragment notificationsFragment = new CategoryFragment();
                return notificationsFragment;

            case 4:
                // settings fragment
                CategoryFragment settingsFragment = new CategoryFragment();
                return settingsFragment;
            default:
                return new HomeFragment();
        }
    }
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawers();
        return;
    }

    // This code loads home fragment when back key is pressed
    // when user is in other fragment than home
    if (shouldLoadHomeFragOnBackPress) {
        // checking if user is on other navigation menu
        // rather than home
        if (navItemIndex != 0) {
            navItemIndex = 0;
            CURRENT_TAG = TAG_HOME;
            loadHomeFragment();
            return;
        }
    }

    super.onBackPressed();
}



    //end navigation
    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(MaterialTab tab) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        pager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(MaterialTab tab) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(MaterialTab tab) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }




    private class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

        public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);

        }

        public Fragment getItem(int num) {

            switch (num) {
                case 0:
                    return new HomeFragmentCheck();
                case 1:
                    return new CategoryFragmentCheck();
                case 2:
                    return new FavouriteFragment();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 3;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.home, menu);


    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menuItem)
    {       
        switch (menuItem.getItemId()) 
        {
        case R.id.about: 
            Intent intab=new Intent(MainActivity.this,AboutActivity.class);
            startActivity(intab);
            break;

            case R.id.update:

                showPU();

                break;


        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(menuItem);
        }
        return true;



    }


}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/m_tab_clr"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
        app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />

    <it.neokree.materialtabs.MaterialTabHost
        android:id="@+id/tabHost"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="48dp"
        android:layout_below="@+id/toolbar"
        app:accentColor="@color/m_tab_select_accent_clr"
        app:primaryColor="@color/m_tab_clr" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@+id/ad_linear"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tabHost" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/ad_linear"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >


    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

**app_bar_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.app.apk.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"></FrameLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Comment: Can you provide an image of your expected output? If user click on NavigationView 1st item then what you want to show on screen and when click on 2nd item then what you want to show on screen. For example for 1st item (Fragment with Tabs) and for 2nd item(Fragment without Tabs).

Comment: The `<RelativeLayout>` is listed after the `<NavigationView>`, so the `RelativeLayout` is on top, which is why you can't click the `NavigationView`. The drawer - your `<NavigationView>` - needs to be listed last in the `<DrawerLayout>`. Also, you should have only one other `View` for the main content, so put your `<include>` inside the `<RelativeLayout>` somewhere. Otherwise, it won't be laid out correctly, and you won't be able to click that, either.

Comment: @Mike M Can you help me edit activity_main.xml

Comment: Just move the `<NavigationView>` to the end, right after the closing `</RelativeLayout>` tag, and right above the closing `</DrawerLayout>` tag. Then put the `<include>` inside the `<RelativeLayout>` tags. I can't say exactly where, because I don't know what's in the `<include>`, or what your desired design is.

Comment: @MikeM i just update layout in the <include> app_bar_main.xml

Comment: The main point is to move the `<NavigationView>` to after the `<RelativeLayout>`, after everything else in the `<DrawerLayout>`. It must be the last thing listed inside the `<DrawerLayout>`. That will get the clicks working on the `NavigationView`. After that, do whatever you want to make the rest of it look like you want. I have no idea what your app is supposed to look like.

Comment: I have click item in navigation but not move new frament  What wrong in code fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.ad_linear, fragment, CURRENT_TAG);

Comment: That's a different question. This question was about your `NavigationView` not receiving click events. If you're having problems with your `FragmentTransaction`s, you'll need to post a new question. Please do create a [mcve] first, though.

Comment: Thank you so much!